# How does I edit a cell of a database table in VSCode by keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-code

I am a Legally blind so I use keyboard and screen reader to programming.
I  am checking out VSCode + Oracle Developer for vSCode Extension. I tried to edit a database table but I could not find any shortcut to do so.
I am using the latest version of VSCode in windows 11

Comment: SQL way to edit the table is to use `alter table` statement (if we are talking about a table as an object) or `insert/update/delete/merge` statement (if we are talking about a table as a data container). Any graphical tools act in exactly the same way behind the scenes and generate those commands.

Comment: Yes table as an object. You are right, alter command does so but  graphical tools can do so faster and easier than commands.